# jQuery carousel disappears in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jcarousel, carousel

This is boggling to me! I had a jQuery carousel working just perfectly as an HTML page (see jtroll.com/chd/web/index_jq.html ), but when porting over to WordPress to actually make the site go live, it disappeared completely: [See here.](http://www.cypresshilldevelopment.com/)

What can I do to get that jQuery carousel back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WordPress page has the JavaScript, but not the HTML for the carousel. There is no element with id "slideblock" on that page to apply the carousel effects to.

You also have a few possibly-unrelated JavaScript errors you should fix. If you use Firefox, get the Firebug plugin to debug it. If you use Chrome, use the built-in JavaScript console.

Comment: Okay, that was a bit embarrassing... in the transfer to WordPress, I must have chopped things up poorly. Yikes. But! With the carousel back in, those Javascript errors are still there. And to be honest, I have no idea how to fix them, knowing next to nothing about Javascript! (I definitely know how to pull up the debug console, so I'm seeing the errors it's throwing out, but that's the extent of my capabilities.)

Comment: I've added and overflow:hidden; to the #slideblock for now, until I can figure this out (just so that the extra images in the carousel aren't being displayed haphazardly below the first, since the carousel is broken).

Comment: It looks like the fact that I'm using multiple WordPress plugins is the problem, because they're each calling an instance of jQuery (a contact form plugin, the carousel plugin, etc.). Still working on a solution. This is why WordPress plugins are a bad idea. If I had any real knowledge of this stuff, it'd be better to just custom code it all.

Comment: Properly written WordPress plugins don't interfere with each other as they use WordPress's script dependency system and only one copy of jQuery is loaded -- by WordPress.

Comment: Looks like I have three different jQuery plugins all running together on different pages, but WordPress is making them difficult to function. I'm down to a single error now, on this page: http://www.cypresshilldevelopment.com/ourhomes_portfolio1/ (A large image is supposed to be loading from the thumbnails below it, but it's not appearing right now). If you have any insight on this, it's appreciated, but otherwise I think you successfully called me out on the boneheaded mistake I made above.